# Django Rest Framework List field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use Django rest framework, I have some question for my nested serializers

my Serializers

```
class SerUserSubCreateView(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    is_active = serializers.BooleanField()

class SerUserCreateView(serializers.Serializer):  
    user = SerUserSubCreateView()
    clients_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
```

my views.py

```
class CreateUserView(CreateAPIView):
     serializer_class = serializers.SerUserCreateView
     permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
     queryset = UserClients.objects.all()


     def post(self,request,format=None):
         serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

         if serializer.is_valid():
                .................
```

my context

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "",
        "status": false
    },
    "clients_id": ""
}
```

but I want

```
{
    "user":[
        {
            "email": "",
            "status": false
        },
    ],
    "clients_id": ""
}
```

There have any method? or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class SerUserCreateView(serializers.Serializer):  
    user = serializers.ListSerializer(child=SerUserSubCreateView())
    clients_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Eventually:

```
class SerUserCreateView(serializers.Serializer):  
    user = SerUserSubCreateView(many=True)
    clients_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
```

You need to change your code accordingly - in serializer/deserialize places. Happy coding.